# Responsive JS - issue when resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, resize

I have some JavaScript that I only want to run if the screen size is more than 900px.  So I have this:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 900) {
 $('.menu-item-2477').hover(

 function () {
     $('.menu-item-2477 ul').css({
         display: 'block'
     });
     $('.menu-item-2477 ul').animate({
         height: '100px'
     }, 200);
 },

 function () {
     $('.menu-item-2477 ul').animate({
         height: '0px',
     }, 200, function () {
         $('.menu-item-2477 ul').css({
             display: 'none'
         });
     });
 });
}
```

This works fine when you load the page, but if you change the window size, it ignores the if statement.  I know that I should do some sort of resize function, like wrap the whole thing in

```
$(window).resize(function(){ }
```

but that didn't work when I tried it.  So what can I do to make this work after resizing the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping it in `$(window).resize(function(){})` won't work, as you'd be binding the handlers multiple times on hover.

What you could do is move the `document.documentElement.clientWidth > 900` logic to *inside* the `hover` handlers. So it'd look more like

```
$('.menu-item-2477').hover(
    //Hover in function
    function(){
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 900) {
            ...
        }
    },
    //Hover out function
    function(){
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 900) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

This way it will check the window size on every event, and perform different logic based on that. Nothing will happen on the resize of the window, as it checks only when it needs to know.

Comment: I'm sure this is the correct answer, but I'm getting a syntax error - it doesn't like the "if" there....

Comment: Sorry @Gwendydd, I made a mistake in my example. They should be wrapped in an anonymous function that will run on hover in and out. It's fixed now